# Infinite loop generator in C

Tags: c

I tried this code in C

```
 unsigned char c= 150;
 for (unsigned char i = 0; i < (2*c); ++i)
 {
    // do something;
 }
```

The program never halts. Why?

Comment: Typically `2` is a 32-bit integer, and hence `2*c = 300` (32-bit). However an `unsigned char` is at most `255`.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1, (i.e. 8 bits), so the maximum value it can hold is (2^8 - 1) which is 255. Hence, `unsigned char` cannot hold values over 255, after which the count restarts from 0. In your case, the loop condition `i < 300` is always true, because `c` resets to `0` once it reaches 255.

To understand why it resets to zero, see the binary representation of 255. 255 can be written in binary as

```
11111111
```

which is 8 bits. So far so good.

If you add 1 to it, then the value becomes

```
100000000
```

which is 9 bits. Since `unsigned char` can store only 1 byte (or 8 bits), the most significant bit `1` is discarded and only the least significant 8 bits get stored in the variable. As a result, `00000000` is what gets stored in `c`, thus making it 0 again.